# How to perform a simple Couchbase Lite query

Tags: c#, couchbase-lite

I wanted to know how it's possible to do some simple CouchbaseLite queries.

I have a document named `"test"`, with key-values `"id": 5` and `"name":"My first test"`.

I wanted to search following:

- I want to get the id (5) where name = "My first test".
- I also wanted to know if this name = "My first test" entry is already available?  I only wanted to add it if it's not there.

```
Database db = new Database("test_db");

using (var testDoc = new MutableDocument("test"))
{
      testDoc.SetInt("id", 5)
             .SetString("name", "My first test");

      db.Save(testDoc);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question right that you want to fetch documents with a specific property value only if it exists, you can do something like this

```
 var query = QueryBuilder.Select(SelectResult.expression(Meta.id),
                SelectResult.expression(Expression.property("id")))
    .From(DataSource.Database(db))
.Where(Expression.Property("name").NotNullOrMissing()
.And(Expression.Property("name").EqualTo(Expression.string("My first test"))))
```

Alternatively, if you know the Id of the document, it would be faster to do a [GetDocument](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.6.0/couchbase-lite-net/api/Couchbase.Lite.Database.html#Couchbase_Lite_Database_GetDocument_System_String_) with the Id. Once you have the document, do a [GetString](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.6.0/couchbase-lite-net/api/Couchbase.Lite.Document.html#Couchbase_Lite_Document_GetString_System_String_) on the name property. If it returns null, you can assume it does not exist.

Refer to the documentation on Couchbase Lite query fundamentals [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.6/csharp.html#where-statement).There are several examples. You may also want to check out API specs on [NotNullOrMissing](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.6.0/couchbase-lite-net/api/Couchbase.Lite.Query.IExpression.html#Couchbase_Lite_Query_IExpression_NotNullOrMissing)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!